# How to change Anchor Tag text on Click in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have to toggle the text On view and Hide How do i do that? I tried many but didnt work. I dont want to use Jquery for this. I want to use only angular. Can anyone help me with this??

```
<a  class="history-link view-history-class" id="show-view-address" (click)="view()" >View</a>
```

Component:

```
view : boolean ;
    view(){
            this.view = !this.view
        }
```

For this when i click view It will toggle a table. Then the text should change to Hide. Same when i click hide.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: Add some code so that we can see what text you are trying to toggle!

Comment: I have added the code. Please check.

Comment: Change the anchor tag text `View ` to `Hide` .

Comment: Hey, guys, it's working. Thanks for all your help. I have one more question. I have a checkbox. When I check it the table data which i am toggling should show only show the Active Records and Hide Inactive Records. Can someone Help me with this too. It would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Prakash, if you was helped and found your answer then you should at least accept it and eventually upvote...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <a href = "#" (click) = "on()">{{value}}</a>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  value  = "View";
  toogle = true;

  on(val:boolean){
    //either this
    this.value = (!this.toogle)?"View":"Hide";
    this.toogle = !this.toogle;

    //or this
    this.value = (this.value == "View")?"Hide":"View"; // and remove toogle
  }

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

PLUNKER LINK - https://plnkr.co/edit/Wt8s8HSraBsnx9PzgDrA?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

The shortest answer:

```
 <a  class="history-link view-history-class" id="show-view-address" (click)="view()">{{view ? 'View'  : 'Hide' }}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```js
text: string = "view";

view(){
    this.text = this.text == "view" ? "hide" : "view" 
}
```

```html
<a (click)="view()"> {{ text }}</a>
```

Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IxZosJjLIiZQjrMOzZX1?p=preview)