# How to toggle the text in <a> tag in angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a button on  tag with text "Unfreeze". I want to toggle it to "Freeze" on click on the button. Here is ny code:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary full-width" (click)="clickFreeze($event)">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>Unfreeze</a>

private clickFreeze(event) {
    console.log("event.srcElement.childNodes[1].textContent", event.srcElement.childNodes[1].textContent);
    if(event.srcElement.childNodes[1].textContent =='Unfreeze'){
      event.srcElement.innerText="Freeze and Save";
    } else if(event.srcElement.innerText =='Freeze and Save'){
      event.srcElement.innerText="Unfreeze";
    }
}
```

For some reason it does not work.  `event.srcElement.childNodes[1].textContent` is equal to "Unfreeze" when I console it but it does not enter the if loop.

Comment: <a class="btn btn-primary full-width" (click)="clickFreeze($event)">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
                    Unfreeze
                  </a>

Comment: do not fiddle with the DOM element directly in the model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Anchor Tag text on Click in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231808/how-to-change-anchor-tag-text-on-click-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 14):

I am not sure why you are using this approach, you can simply toggle text conditionally like this -

.html

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="isFreeze = !isFreeze">
  <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
  {{isFreeze ? "Unfreeze" : "Freeze and Save"}}
</a>
```

.ts

```
isFreeze: boolean = true;
```

Comment: thanks for your help but (click)="clickFreeze() is doing other stuff as well so I cannot use (click)="isFreeze = !isFreeze"

Comment: @YogeshMali yes you can simply call function like you said and do the same there, you defiantly can customise as per your requirements.